# Python: Edge List to an Adjacency Matrix using SciPy/Pandas shows IndexError: column index (3) out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, edges

I have a text file with an Edge List (`egde.txt`):

```
1 1 0.00000000000000000000
1 2 0.25790529076045041
1 3 0.77510411846367422
2 1 0.34610027855153203
2 2 0.00000000000000000000
2 3 0.43889275766016713
3 1 0.75335810231494713
3 2 0.22234924264075450
3 3 0.00000000000000000000
```

The weights of the edges are floating values as seen and the separators are white spaces which I must keep that way in the text file. I want to convert this edge list to a ***Matrix*** like the following and store it in a CSV file:

```
    1         2         3
1   0.000000  0.257905  0.775104
2   0.346100  0.000000  0.438893
3   0.753358  0.222349  0.000000
```

I have the following code (`txttocsv2.py`) which I thought would work, but unfortunately does not:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('connectivity.txt', 'r') as fil:

    A = np.genfromtxt(fil)

    i, j, weight = A[:,0], A[:,1], A[:,2]

    dim =  max(len(set(i)), len(set(j)))

    B = sps.lil_matrix((dim, dim))
    for i,j,w in zip(i,j,weight):
        B[i,j] = w

    for row in B: #I want to print the output as well to see if it works
        print(row)

    with open("connect.csv", "wb") as f:
        for row in B:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(B)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "txttocsv2.py", line 16, in <module>
    B[i,j] = w
  File "/home/osboxes/pymote_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/lil.py", line 379, in __setitem__
    i, j, x)
  File "scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx", line 231, in scipy.sparse._csparsetools.lil_fancy_set (scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.c:5041)
  File "scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx", line 376, in scipy.sparse._csparsetools._lil_fancy_set_int32_float64 (scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.c:7021)
  File "scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx", line 87, in scipy.sparse._csparsetools.lil_insert (scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.c:3216)
IndexError: column index (3) out of bounds
```

Could anybody point out where the code is failing and help me out?
Thanks in advance :)
Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM and Python 2.7

Comment: Why not create matrix in pandas with `df.pivot(0, 1, 2)` and use `.to_csv(..)` to save as csv file, where `df` is edgelist?

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks for the response. I am still a beginner to Python, hence it was a bit difficult for me to comprehend your answer. As far as I understood, you are suggesting that I use `DataFrame` and create the matrix, and the `0, 1, 2` in `pivot` are edges `u`, `v` and weight `w` respectively right? How exactly do I modify this to take a text file as input? If possible please post your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to access location `i,j` in matrix `B`.
The problem is `i` and `j` are one-based and the matrix is zero-based.
You should switch to `B[i-1,j-1] = w`. Also, you probably need to change the row `writer.writerow(B)` to `writer.writerow(row)`.

Or like John Galt said, use pandas `pivot`:

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.read_csv('edge.txt', delimiter=' ', header=None).pivot(0,1,2).to_csv('connect.csv', header=False, index=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code worked with `B[i-1,j-1] = w` and there is an output, however I still got an error while writing the output to a CSV file: `raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]` and the error is pointing to the line `writer.writerow(B)`. And the alternative with Pandas I couldn't get it working from the start itself. Could you please post a complete answer if possible? Thanks again :)

Comment: Edited. Can you post the error you get when trying to use pandas?

Comment: Your suggestion with Pandas worked, but I still need the node numbers in the output file as a proper Adjacency Matrix. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I have the node numbers now, I just had to change the `header` and `index` in `to_csv` to `true`. But there's still an issue, there is a `0` occurring in the header in the output as well like `0,1,2,3` where as it should actually be `,1,2,3` in a proper CSV file (no characters before the first comma).

Comment: You can use rename_axis like this: `pd.read_csv('edge.txt', delimiter=' ', header=None).pivot(0,1,2).rename_axis(None).to_csv('connect.csv', header=False, index=False)`

Comment: Finally, I have what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the help! :)